# Finding all words ending in "ion" with regex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm getting 0 matches when using the regex below in JavaScript. I'm trying to find all words that **end** in "ion"

```
/^[a-z]+(ion)$/i
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I've also tried this below, but it doesn't work either:

```
/^[a-z]+ion$/i
```

Edit: This checks against a form text field that will contain only one word:

- Example
- example
- nation
- Nation

Comment: What's your input? If there's multiple words then the `^` and `$` need to be removed.

Comment: Please provide example strings. Possibly `[a-z]+ion\b`

Comment: `ion\b` should be enough based on what you want. match `i`, followed by `o`, followed by `n`, followed by end word (`\b`, this is a word boundary).

Comment: Your original Regex works fine if you add the /m flag to have ^ and $ match beginning/end of line.